# How to fit different ARMA models by group in R?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, arma

I have $Y$ measurements per several Subjects and I'm studying impact of factor on $Y$ measurements. I've fit a lognormal mixed model with a random interaction, but I'm finding autoregressive dependence on residuals. However, some exploration suggests different temporal dependence per subject.

Can `lme()` incorporate different autoregressive dependence by subject? That is, can `lme()` implement a different AR order per subject?

I could do this fairly easily by dividing the residuals by subject and using the function `ar()`. But I'm hoping there's a more cohesive alternative in R.

Comment: Question about programming are better suited for stack overflow.

Comment: @BabakP This isn't a question about programming; just because one uses R, which also happens to be a programming language, doesn't make such question programming ones. This is clearly about the use of statistical software.

Comment: @Gavin perhaps programming was not the right word, but i still think the question is off topic since it is basically asking can this software do what I want.  I would like to hear from a moderator on this.

Comment: @BabakP Read [this](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1744/1390) It is a confused mess. By some accounts there (though whuber's is the only Moderator one IIRC) this is OT because the Q title says "...in R" (yes, I'm being slightly facetious!). It could be rephrased to pass this test. Personally, no-one does applied stats with pencil & paper or mechanical calculators today; people use computers, & most often they use software, that they didn't write, on those computers. It is hard to separate the *statistics* from the *application* or *software* implementation. Here I disagree with whuber.

Comment: @BabakP Regardless of whether this is or is not on topic for CV, this is *most certainly not* on topic for [so].

Comment: Well if it were up to me, I would like to see this question revised to reflect more statistical theory/calculations rather than "Can lme() incorporate different autoregressive dependence by subject? That is, can lme() implement a different AR order per subject?" Which to me seems once again like asking can this software do what I want.

Comment: @Gavin I can't tell what you are disagreeing with me *about*. Would you care to explain? I certainly don't recognize any of my thoughts in the statements you appear to be disagreeing with.

Comment: @whuber your answer there includes "'How do I do a factor analysis in R'" as an example of OT but one which could be made on-topic by removing the R related things, thus making the Q more generic & less platform specific. This is a theme that you have expressed on a number occasions. I don't agree with that position. I find responses such as the initial comment here i) don't understand what [so] is (for one), ii) are inconsistently applied across CV, and iii) aren't very helpful to CV as a whole. I don't see what the problem with Qs like this is? Agree tho we don't want [stats.se] == R Help.

Comment: @Gavin We may be miscommunicating, but this is not the place to find out in detail where my posts could be clarified. Your [meta post](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1765) is a good place to continue this conversation. Here I would just like to mention that I am *not* defending the initial comment and I have *not* voted to close this question. In the future, though, I hope you will be a little more restrained and think harder before publicly accusing people of lack of knowledge, of writing "confused messes," etc.: that unconstructive approach just makes you sound petty and mean.

Comment: @whuber Not to prolong this comment thread, but my point was that there are differing opinions on what is or is not OT, yours was the only Mod opinion I found when I wrote the comment, my only point here was to say that I don't agree with your position entirely in the thread I linked to, and finally I didn't mean to put words in your mouth or imply you would have closed this Q&A, apologies for that.

Answer (score 4):

The specific answer is no, this is not how `lme()` works. `corAR1()` will estimate a single additional parameter $\phi$ which is the AR(1) coefficient applied *within* any specified nesting via argument `form`. In other words, the same AR(1) is then assumed for, in your case, each subject.

The same applies to `corARMA()`; a single estimate of of the AR and MA parameters is made, across all levels of any grouping factor. Hence if you specify an ARMA(2,1), the same ARMA(2,1) is assumed to operate within the levels of the grouping factor.

You could investigate this for yourself by fitting a model with an AR correlation structure for residuals nested within subject `corAR1(form = time | subject)` and note the change in model degrees of freedom compared with a model fitted without the `corAR1()`.

Specifically, when you specify say `corAR1(form = time | subject)`, you are asking `lme()` to estimate a single parameter $\phi$ which is then applied within the groups defined by `subject` *and* that there is **zero** correlation between groups (`subject`s).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was aware of the standard implementation of lme fitting on ARMA type model for within group temporal dependance by potentially assuming independent subjects (an adequate assumption in my case). There's several ways around it, but wanted to make sure there wasn't a cohesive way to construct this model

Comment: @Rob Nope, only option I know is to go Bayesian and cook the correlations yourself. Or you could look at adapting the current `corStruct` methods/functions to do what you want, but that would be quite involved especially if you aren't familiar with **nlme**; these are extensible by the user and can be quite flexible, e.g. the **mgcv** package.

Comment: A Bayesian implementation would not be necessary. What I did is that I included a lagged version of the response as a covariate. Granted, the estimate of this coefficient will be biased, but as long as the other assumptions of the model hold, the estimator will be fairly consistent and efficient. Besided, the intention of the model was for interpretation of a main covariate and not prediction. The other model assumptions were fine, and the temporal dependence had disappeared in the ACF plot (in the previous model it displayed exponential decay).

Comment: Strangely, acf plots of the previous model (with no lag response) by subject suggested different AR orders per Subject. When fitting an lme using corAR1() the temporal association was not being modeled properly. But when I used a lagged version of the response, the ACF plot did not suggest temporal dependance. A different slope for the lagged response didn't dramatically improve on the original lagged response model. By accounting for the temporal dependance this way, I have effectively being able to focus on the main covariate of interest.

Comment: @Rob Good point about explicitly modelling using the lag1 covariate - I'd overlooked that. I was thinking more of using the Bayesian tools and something convenient to allow computation of different within group AR(1)s. Perhaps you should add your modelling lag1 as a Answer to your Question?